# Not able to install maven in windows 8

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automation

I am not experienced with `apache maven` before. i used to with selenium automation tools where `apache maven` is required.

I have followed steps detail

1. Download apache-maven-3.5.0 and put that in `C:\`
2. Set path for `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` in ***`system Variable`***
   **Variable name  : M2_HOME
   Variable value : C:\apache-maven-3.5.0.
   Variable name  : MAVEN_HOME
   Variable value : C:\apache-maven-3.5.0.**
3. And add `C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin` in `Path` variable (in ***system Variable***)
4. I checked in command window that java installed and also make sure that JDK path in `JAVA_HOME` which is proper

But, After following above all steps when i run command (in command window) `mvn -version` its shows me following message. Any help would be appreciable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g61A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME is pointing to a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) installation which is not the same as a JDK (Java Development Kit).

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131` is a correct value for a JDK while  `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131` is not.

Maven *requires* a JDK here, a JRE is not enough.

Look for JDK on the [Oracle Java Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I have added jdk path in JAVA_HOME variable please check screenshot. but still its shows same error in cmd

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set up two environment variables in order to complete your maven installation:

1. `JAVA_HOME` must be set to the path where you have your Java Development Kit (JDK) installed;
2. `PATH` or `Path` must include the path to the `bin` directory of your Maven installation, exactly as per step 3 in your question.

The `M2_HOME` and/or `MAVEN_HOME` environment variables are **not** required and may cause confusion if set incorrectly or if you need to support multiple versions of Maven later.

> If this does not work then please provide the output of:
>      * %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -version
>      * echo %Path%